# C++ linking between headers and source files

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. Look the following code:

```
// in myclass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
 void foo();
 int bar;
};


// in myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"

void MyClass::foo()
{
 // does something
}


//in main.cpp
#include "myclass.h"  // defines MyClass

int main()
{
  MyClass a;
  return 0;
}
```

as far as I understand, in order to make interfaces separated from implementations, the source code file `main.cpp` includes the header file `myclass.h`; the latter contains the attributes and the prototypes of the methods within class `MyClass`, but not the implementation of those methods which are instead contained by `myclass.cpp`. In turn `myclass.cpp is` including `myclass.h`.

Can someone explain me how exactly the compiler links the prototype contained in a header file to its actual implementation?

In this particular case, I am asking how `myclass.h` is linked toward `myclass.cpp`.

Comment: @mindriot I'm sure we have better dupes.

Comment: Every good C++ book should explain the difference between preprocessor, compiler and linker.

Comment: I'd put this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work